# PHP decrement NULL value issue

Tags: php, null, increment, decrement

I have noticed if a value is `null` i can increment it by one using `++$value` but its not true about decrement , meaning `--$value` would return `null` , why?

```
$value = null;
echo ++$value; // 1
echo --$value; // null (I'm expecting -1)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ref# [language.operators.increment.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

> Note: The increment/decrement operators only affect numbers and
>   strings. Arrays, objects and resources are not affected. Decrementing
>   NULL values has no effect too, but incrementing them results in 1.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it in a logical sense.

You can't take something away from nothing, but you can add something to nothing. Null is not 0, it is simply no value.

Comment: Except PHP coerces null values to 0 in math operations. If you do `$val = null - 1` in PHP it works. If you do `$val--` it doesn't work. I thought decrement and increment were just shorthands.